# Unable to view new AD Attribute when using a function

Tags: powershell, active-directory

We created two new attributes in AD (UguestRole, UguestRoleDtl).  Trying the following PowerShell function will not show the new attributes.

I can manually run the get portion of the script and the attributes will show.

```
Function Admin-CheckAD {

$UserID = $IsUser = ""

Clear-Host
Write-Host "Get Active Directory Data"
$UserID = ""
$UserID = Read-Host "Enter User ID"

If ($UserID) {
    $IsUser = Get-AdUser -LDAPFilter "(sAMAccountName=$UserID)"
    If ($IsUser -eq $Null){
        Write-Warning "User does not exist in AD";Return
    } Else {
        Get-Aduser $UserID -Properties samaccountname, DisplayName, LastLogonDate, PasswordLastSet, PasswordExpired, Mail, Enabled, UguestRole, UguestRoleDtl, AccountExpirationDate, Description |
        Select-Object @{N='User ID';E={($_.samaccountname).ToUpper()}}, DisplayName, LastLogonDate, PasswordLastSet, PasswordExpired, Mail, Enabled, UguestRole, UguestRoleDtl, @{N='Expire Date';E={([DateTime]$psitem.AccountExpirationDate).AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString()}}, Description |
        Format-List
      }
    }
}
```

I expect to see...

```
User ID         : JOEUSER
DisplayName     : User, Joe
LastLogonDate   : 6/10/2019 6:29:21 AM
PasswordLastSet : 5/22/2019 10:05:43 AM
PasswordExpired : False
Mail            : joe.user@email.com
Enabled         : True
UguestRole      : CC
UguestRoleDtl   : Builder
Expire Date     :
Description     : CC User
```

But all I get is...

```
User ID         : JOEUSER
Name            : User, Joe
LastLogonDate   : 6/10/2019 6:29:21 AM
PasswordLastSet : 5/22/2019 10:05:43 AM
PasswordExpired : False
Mail            : joe.user@email.com
Enabled         : True
Expire Date     :
Description     : CC User
```

Comment: Does `Get-Aduser "username" properties *` show the attributes?

Comment: Yes, it does.  Thanks

Comment: Don't use `-properties *` in production use. It is a bad practice and unnecessarily slow by pulling non cached properties. Probably not a huge deal for one user but I don't know where you are going to take this knowledge. Lets see if we have fix the real problem.

Comment: You should not need to specify `Format-List` as that would be automatic for objects with as many properties as yours. If you remove it does that go away? ugestrole is not a standard attribute either. Did you extend your schema to include that?

Comment: I removed `Format-List` and the new attributes still do not show.

Comment: The weird thing is those look like the default property set for aduser objects.... like your select statement is not part of the pipe as we here.

Comment: A side note... .it is redundant to query for the user twice. I would just query it once with a `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` on the end. You can still use your `if` to display a warning and return what you find.

Comment: If you need non-default properties, you can (and should) specify them in the `-properties` parameter - in your case, `Get-ADUser -Identity JOEUSER -Properties UGuestRole,UGuestRoleDTL`. You may also have to pipe the object to `Select-Object -Properties *`.

Comment: Does `Get-ADObject -Searchbase ("CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC={0}" -f ((get-adforest).name -split "\." -join ",DC=")) -Filter "ldapdisplayname -eq 'UGuestRole'"` return any data?

Comment: What is weird is I have this function in a script that I call from my PS profile when I open PS.  If I open the script and run it again, the function shows the new attributes.  All the other functions work as expected.

Comment: And even more weirdness.  I copied the function and saved it as its own ps1 file and then added that file as part of my PS profile.  It shows the new attributes now.